# Не удается получить доступ к сайту Node.js + express.js

Tags: node.js, express

Создание сервера:

```
const exress = require('express')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

const app = exress()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello')
})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server starting http://localhost:${PORT}/`))
```

Зависимост package.json

```
{
  "name": "np",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon ./index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "pg": "^8.7.3"
  }
}
```

Сервер в консоли работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако я не могу получит доступ к сайту:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запрос в программе postman также выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите решить пожалуйста эту проблему

Comment: Ошибок в коде нет, при запуске сервера тоже ошибок нет) Вы запускаете сервер на своем ПК? мб так вставьте `app.listen(PORT,  '0.0.0.0',`

Comment: А где вы его запускаете? И ещё, стоит `PORT` явно привести к числу.

Comment: @ПавелСоляник еще такой нюанс, в консоле у вас по разному идет лог старта.. в коде `server starting http://localhost:` а первый лог пишет `server start on PORT`.. должно быть одинаково

Answer (score 0):

У меня на компьютере установлен postgres сервер. Он работал на 5000 порту, когда я открывал данный url, фактически открывалась несуществующая страница сервера postgres, но не моего приложения.

Решением было одно, поменять порт на любой другой в моем приложении.

Comment: очень странно что node не выдовал ошибку что порт уже используется